# Calling a partial view in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This might be a duplicate title but I have a different question. I have this code

```
 public ActionResult _FieldAssignmentView()
    {
        Shift shift = new Shift();
        Person person = new Person();
        Signatory sig = new Signatory();
        ViewBag.ShiftId = new SelectList(db.Shifts, "ShiftId", "ShiftDesc", shift.ShiftId);
        var empid = (from p in db.People join s1 in db.Employees on p.PersonId equals s1.PersonId select new { CompleteName = p.CompleteName, s1.EmployeeId });
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(empid, "EmployeeId", "CompleteName", null).OrderBy(m => m.Text);

        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "divisionhead") && Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "director"))
        {
            return PartialView("_FieldAssignment");
        }           
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_FieldAssignmentForEmployee");               
        }
      //  return View();
    }
```

Now my question it is possible to return two(2) partial view?.
I have four partial views (1,2,3,4) and I duplicate the view 1 and 4 for the employee log.in to disabled a certain button. For example the employee will log.in view 1 and 4 will return in my else code.
If possible how?. Thanks.

Comment: More information required.  Your code is currently returning one partial view based on role.  What do you want to do?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams sorry about that. I have 4 partial views(1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ) and I created a same partial view ex. Partial view 1 and 4 but a certain button is disabled if the employee is log.in. So far I only manage to do is 1 partial view to return.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include this extra information.  The quick answer is yes, you can return different partial views based on conditional checks, however your question is too ambiguous to answer as yet - especially considering it does not mention this extra information in your comment.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams there I hope it is okay now.

Comment: @YurkZ Sorry I am confused. You want to return 2 views together ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes if possible?. Because I have a condition if the employee is log.in a button in partial view 1 and 4 is disabled. I can't think other way to solve my problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example the employee will log.in view 1 and 4 will return in my
>   else code. If possible how?

You can create another container partial view in which you include the other 2 partial views.

LoggedInUserView.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("_FieldAssignment")
@Html.Partial("_FieldAssignmentForEmployee")
```

Now in your else condition, you can return this view

```
return PartialView("LoggedInUserView.cshtml");
```

If you want to disable a button in any of these views, You can add a boolean property to your view model and set the value in your action method and use that to conditionally show a disabled/enabled button

```
public class FieldAssignmentViewModel
{
   public bool IsAllowedToAssign {set;get;}
}
```

and in your action method,

```
var vm = new FieldAssignmentViewModel();
vm.IsAllowedToAssign = true; // Set this value based on your custom condition.
return View(vm);
```

Now, the view you are passing this object should be strongly typed to our view model.

_FieldAssignment.cshtml

```
@model FieldAssignmentViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 @if(Model.IsAllowedToAssign)
 {
   <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
 }
 else
 {
   <input type="button" disabled value="Assign" /> 
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm just starting in asp mvc. In  action method how/where should I use that code?

Comment: It is written in my answer.

Comment: If i put it in my ActionResult it says unreachable code detected

Comment: That means you are returning before that code. That code should be put in conjunction with your other code(condition checking)

Comment: I edited my code above. Thats all my code in controller action.

Comment: in which view you want to disable the button ? make it strongly typed to the view model and pass the object to that view/partial view.

Comment: As my example I have four views. I duplicated the 1st and 4th view for the employee log.in. If the employee is log.in the duplicated view thhat has a disabled button will show not the original view.

Comment: You do not need the duplicated view(with disabled button). You can use the same view, but show the enable/disable based on the view model property value. I suggest you do some good  reading on the basics of mvc, views passing models/viewmodels to views etc.

Comment: Okay I will. Thanks for the time and I will use your method and I will try to understand it.